# Difference between GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer and new GrizzlyWebServer WebServer

Tags: java, rest, jersey, grizzly

I am creating RESTful web services using Jersey and an embedded Grizzly web server.

I see that there are two ways to create an embedded Grizzly web server. Can anyone tell me the difference between the two?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,  ConfigurationException,    DBException, DaxException {
    GrizzlyWebServer gws = new GrizzlyWebServer(8085, "/var/www");
    ServletAdapter jerseyAdapter = new ServletAdapter();

    jerseyAdapter.addInitParameter(
        PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES,"com.merchant.services");
    jerseyAdapter.setServletInstance(new ServletContainer());

    gws.addGrizzlyAdapter(jerseyAdapter, new String[]{"/"});

    // let Grizzly run
    gws.start();
}
```

And second way is:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.merchant.services");
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
httpServer.start();
```

With the first way its easy to configure the web server.

Answer (score 3):

## 1

`Grizzly Web Serve` with `ServletAdapter` approach is to support JAX-RS along with `Servlet` and `Filters`.which gives you,

**jersey + ServletContainer**

This will give you ample flexibility to provide more complex configuration

## 2

If you think `ServletContainer` being an additional dependency use the second one.which is,

**jersey + Simple Http server**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So do I imply that the underlying  WebServer implementation is the same? Is GrizzlyWeb Server a production quality web server ? Why should one consider grizzly over tomcat or netty?

Comment: One major difference that I've found is that with jersey + Simple Http Server is you have a lack of access to commonly needed data (e.g., remote client IP address) via the HttpRequestContext that is accessible with a HttpServletRequest (which is only available if configured with the ServletContainer).  There's a bug on Jersey's JIRA indicating an interest in getting that information in HttpRequestContext, but it's currently "open/unresolved" after 2 years (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-473).